# radio button with custom background image turns black in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, radio-button, background-image

I need to render radiobuttons on my site with specific background-images:
[not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEQnX.png)
, [checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBRGo.png)

I solved this problem by adding the following styles for radiobutton elements:

```
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-image: url(/Images/notChackedRadioButton.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Everything was fine, but when i open my site in Internet Explorer I see that [all radiobuttons became black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QuZL.png).
Seems like IE adds its own image above my background image, but I don't have any idea how to solve this. Please, any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the rest of your code here is an example of a way you can do it. Works in IE 11 and IE Edge. Found on codepen for rest of the example - https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/bgqYJz

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}


input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:19px;
  height:19px;
  margin:-2px 10px 0 0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/check_radio_sheet.png) -38px top no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/check_radio_sheet.png) -57px top no-repeat;
}
```

```html
      <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rr" />
      <label for="r1"><span></span>Radio Button 1</label>
      <p>
      <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rr" />
      <label for="r2"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>
```